# Add guest user to group during signup flow with azure ad b2b

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2b

Apologies if this question is too general.

I have created a signup/signin flow in Azure AD External Identities, using a Google Identity Provider , and added my application to this user flow.
The flow itself works as expected, as during signup the user is created, however after inserting the password, I get the following error :

```
The signed in user is not assigned to a role for the application
```

This error makes sense, as during signup the guest user is not added to any group nor given any roles, which it needs to access the application.

My question is, is there a way to give the necessary roles/add the user to a default group during the signup/signin flow process? Or alternatively, set a default group for all guest users that are added to the AD?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Dynamic Group Membership**. If the users meet the defined rules criteria, they will be automatically assigned to the group.

**Note:** Premium P1 license is needed to use this feature.

**Reference:**

[Create Group Rules to assign users to the group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/groups-create-rule)

**OR**

You can also create a Powershell script to automatically assign new users to enterprise application.

**Reference:**

[Add User To Azure AD Application Powershell](https://github.com/ruudmens/LazyAdmin/blob/master/Azure%20Runbook/AddUserToAzureADApplication.ps1)